# Changing the text of a Jlabel from another method

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, textlabel

I apologize if the solution to this question is obvious, I am sure the solution is simple, I just cant seem to get it right in my head.

I have created my JFrame as shown in the code below. I am looking to change the text of a label ( lblStatus ) from within my main method and I cant seem to get it working. Do I need to create a new instance of the label or something along those lines ?

Can anyone advise me on what approach to take ?

Regards,
         Dan.

NB- I have removed some content to highlight the relevant code.

```
public class server {

private JFrame frmCorbaServer;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                server window = new server();
                window.frmCorbaServer.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // SERVER CONTENT
        // If connection made
        System.out.println("Server connected"); // I want this to display in lblStatus!


}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public server() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frmCorbaServer = new JFrame();
    frmCorbaServer.setTitle("server 0.1");
    frmCorbaServer.setResizable(false);
    frmCorbaServer.setBounds(100, 100, 257, 153);
    frmCorbaServer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmCorbaServer.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblStatus = new JLabel("...");
    lblServant.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    lblServant.setBounds(10, 36, 231, 14);
    frmCorbaServer.getContentPane().add(lblServant);
}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

JLabel should be an instance member. An handler will help you modify the Label's text in instance methods.

```
public class server
{
   private JLabel lblStatus= new JLabel("Text") ; 

   public void changeLabel(String text) 
   {
     lblStatus.setText(text) ;
   } 

}
```

In main: `window.changeLabel("In main") ;`

This has to be done because in your initialize method, there reference to `lblStatus` is lost

```
private void initialize() {
    frmCorbaServer = new JFrame();
    frmCorbaServer.setTitle("server 0.1");
    frmCorbaServer.setResizable(false);
    frmCorbaServer.setBounds(100, 100, 257, 153);
    frmCorbaServer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmCorbaServer.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblStatus = new JLabel("..."); // Forgotten when method finishes
    lblServant.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    lblServant.setBounds(10, 36, 231, 14);
    frmCorbaServer.getContentPane().add(lblServant);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Lews. I am getting an error however. "cannot make a static reference to a non static method"

Comment: Only main is static. I am calling `server.changeLabel("connected")` in main.

Comment: `window cannot be resolved` :/. I really need to brush up on my basic java skills.

Comment: Its located in `run()` as shown in the code. Im calling `window.changelevel("")` in main. Should I create a window variable outside of run? Just to note that I built this GUI with WindowBuilder in Eclipse. I didnt think it would make things this akward.

Comment: Use server window = null in main, before EventQueue.InvokeLater. The inner class should then be able to access it. And it will be visible in main as well.

Comment: ok, I've added `server window = null;` in before EventQueue.InvokeLater and im now getting a `NullPointerException` Error, lol.

Comment: Mmn right, of course that won't work. Do you use window anywhere apart from the run method? Pastebin link to show me what you are doing..

Comment: Heres the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/cM5BNzxX. You can Ignore most of the CORBA code, its functioning correctly. Cheers for all your help on this btw.

Comment: @L337BEAN http://pastebin.com/szL55k4j Let me know if that works.. change some bit as you see fit. Remove "window = new server();" in run method from the pastebin link.

Comment: There seems to be an issue on line 47. And I removed `window = new server();` But its still complaining on line 46 of the pastebin that window needs a `final` modifier. Changing it to final throws up more errors.

Comment: Ok I thought your server throws an exception. http://pastebin.com/a10THaUA Oh and remove that line again.. I keep forgetting :(

Comment: Ah! It compiles and runs. No text in the label though :/. Do I need to call a redraw or something those lines ? I was sure sing took care of that.

Comment: Or It must have to be "wired" to `JLabel lblServant` somehow ?

Comment: If you are changing the text of lblServant, yes. Look at the code in my answer as an example.

Comment: You should not call `setText(..)` from another `Thread` as it is not thread safe, wrap external calls to `setText(..)` in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` block, so calls run on `Event Dispatch Thread` of GUI

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with CORBA programming, so I can only answer with some general advice. First you need to know when the server connects. Most likely this doesn't occur in your `main()` method. Is there a listener or some other callback method which is called to notify you that the server is connected?

Once you figure out that part, changing the text of a JLabel is fairly easy. First you need to declare an instance variable:

```
private JLabel lblStatus;
```

When you create the JLabel in `initialize()`, you don't need the declaration:

```
lblStatus = new JLabel("...");
```

Finally, when you know that the server has connected, simply call the `setText()` method:

```
lblStatus.setText("Server connected");
```

Comment: Could you show an example in relation to my code if possible ? As you can see from above. Im having alot of trouble with this.